# Why is the comparison between const char[] and const char* different?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have the following code:

```
const char str1[] = "asdasd";
const char str2[] = "asdasd";
const char* str3 = "dsadsa";
const char* str4 = "dsadsa";
if (str1 == str2)
{
    cout << "str1 == str2" << endl;
}
if (str3 == str4)
{
    cout << "str3 == str4" << endl;
}
```

The result is "str3 == str4". Why?

Comment: Choose different compiler options that merges / pools strings, then `str3 != str4`.

Comment: What's the point of comparing the pointers? What's this code supposed to achieve?

Comment: Note also what happens if it's not const.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*For C++*

`str3` and `str4` are pointing to identical [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal),

> The compiler is allowed, but not required, to combine storage for equal or overlapping string literals. That means that identical string literals may or may not compare equal when compared by pointer.

That means whether `str3 == str4` is `true` or `false` is *unspecified*, it depends on the implementation, and the one you're using gives `true`.

On the other hand, `str1` and `str2` are independent arrays.

> String literals can be used to initialize character arrays. If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string `"foo"`.

So `str1 == str2` is guaranteed to be `false`.

Comment: "That means [the result] is implementation-defined" -- that means that it **depends on the implementation**. "Implementation defined" in the standard means that the implementation **must document** its behavior. I don't know of any such requirement for string literals.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right; it should be *unspecified*.

Answer (score 5):

String literal pooling. Compilers tend to merge identical string literals, so there's only one copy in the program. This is allowed but not required; it would be unwise to rely on this happening.